# Objects with Array values into a tree

Tags: javascript, json, tree

I have an array of objects where every object has an array of values. The data structure is not ideal but it's the only way I can access it. I'm trying to turn this structure into a tree structure so I can build a D3 indented collapsible table.

I've tried to modify some previous answers I've found but have yet to be successful. Here is a link to the current JSFiddle I've been working on.

http://jsfiddle.net/COLTstreet/fsve7w2L/25/

This is a small example of how the data comes to me.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "items": [
        "All Other",
        "4C FOODS CORP"
      ],
      "hints": {
        "index": 0
      }
    },
    {
      "items": [
        "All Other",
        "PBNA"
      ],
      "hints": {
        "index": 14
      }
    },
    {
      "items": [
        "All Other",
        "PRIVATE LABEL"
      ],
      "hints": {
        "index": 15
      }
    },
    {
      "items": [
        "Base Water",
        "CCNA"
      ],
      "hints": {
        "index": 18
      }
    },
    {
      "items": [
        "Base Water",
        "CRYSTAL GEYSER"
      ],
      "hints": {
        "index": 19
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I need the code to finish like this:

```
[
  {
    "Category": "All Other",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "4C FOODS CORP"
      },
      {
        "name": "PBNA"
      },
      {
        "name": "PRIVATE LABEL"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Category": "Base Water",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "CCNA"
      },
      {
        "name": "CRYSTAL GEYSER"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: it's less than a tree, but more a grouping with a single level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to first use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) in conjunction with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to generate an `object` for group the elements by the category, and in a second step use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the generated object `entries` to get the desired output:

```js
const input = {
  "data": [
    {"items": ["All Other", "4C FOODS CORP"], "hints": {"index": 0}},
    {"items": ["All Other", "PBNA"], "hints": {"index": 14}},
    {"items": ["All Other", "PRIVATE LABEL"], "hints": {"index": 15}},
    {"items": ["Base Water", "CCNA"], "hints": {"index": 18}},
    {"items": ["Base Water", "CRYSTAL GEYSER"], "hints": {"index": 19}}
  ]
};

// Group by the category.
let res = input.data.reduce((acc, {items: [cat, val]}) =>
{
    acc[cat] = acc[cat] || [];
    acc[cat].push({name: val});
    return acc;
}, {});

// Generate desired output structure.
res = Object.entries(res).map(([k, v]) => ({category: k, children: v}));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```